# Animation on iOS email clients

Tags: jquery, ios, css, animation, email-client

Is there any way to do an animation with CSS3 or Jquery on email campaigns? Does the email clients have support for this? My target is iOS devices(iPhone, iPad).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321762/sending-html-email-having-jquery-scripts) could help for you. Is not exactly make animation but is related to add jquery. [This](http://www.pure360.com/blog/blog-entries/CSS3-Animation-in-email) would help too for animation using css into embedded email.